# Проблема imageButton

Tags: android

Добрый день, создаю небольшое приложение, решил использовать ImageButton`ы с наложенными на них изображениями. Однако при подключении изображений, получается несуразица. Вот что должно наложится:

[image: иконка]

А вот что получается:

[image: приложение]

Ниже  main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.calculator.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.019">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.948">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="76dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/calc1" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Изображение в формате .png. Что не так делаю?

Comment: ConstraintLayout - одноуровневый контейнер, он не подразумевает какой то вложенности каких бы то ни было других контейнеров. Вы хотите, чтобы разработчики google поседели видя, как вы вкладываете один констрайнт в другой, да еще и LinaearLayout впридачу, когда они проделали огромную работу, чтобы этого не происходило никогда.  Если у вас непреодолимое желание вкладывать контейнеры, а не использовать линейную верстку - откажитесь от ConstraintLayout, так как вы не пользуетесь его возможностями, в пользу более "легких" контейнеров

Comment: указывать размеры виджетов в dp - так же грубейшее нарушение принципов верстки в андоид. Вам срочно нужно освоить адаптивную верстку, иначе вам придется делать отдельную разметку под каждый тип экрана (их сотни комбинаций), что неприемлемо уже по соображениям банальной логики

Comment: я пока осваиваюсь, до верстки дело тоже дойдет со временем. Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо app:srcCompat="@drawable/calc1" используй android:background
Скажу на заметку, у тебя есть например ImageView 200x200, если использовать src, то оно не будет вмещать изображение на ImageView 200x200, а будет поставить так, как его реальный размер, как видите на картинке только маленькая часть от этой изображении.. а android:background берет например 1920x1080 картинку и вмещает на 200x200, так чтобы все было видно.

Comment: какой смысл использовать бэкграунд в ImageButton, когда он специально создан, чтобы выводить изображение в форграунд?

Comment: Ладно, тогда делай изображение размером твоего Imageview

Answer (score 1):

Разрешения экранов  бывают различные. Ваше изображение не сжимается под размер кнопки, оно отображается в своём разрешении и вы видите только его кусочек. Чтобы на любом разрешении экрана ваше приложение выглядело одинаково стараться придется именно вам, сам андроид не подгонит под размер экрана. Так что советую вам ознакомиться с темой поддержки различных экранов.  [Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) 
 
      Если ближе к делу вы  можете использовать либо nine-patch изображения, которые будут сжиматься. Закинули одно nine-patch изображение и оно будет растягиваться по определенным заданным параметрам. [Вот статья по этому поводу](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/draw9patch.php)  

Второй вариант: создавать отдельное изображение для каждого из экранов и раскладывать их по папкам drawable-hdpi , drawable-xhdpi и так далее. Андроид сам выберет нужное изображение для текущего экрана.

Comment: есть еще VectorDrawable

Comment: Да конечно, но человеку не поняв еще как к кнопке правильно изображение прикрутить, не стоит в векторную графику нырять.